# C# Binding does not work?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am trying to bing a grid size (i.e. Width and Height) to one of its child (i.e. a Viewbox). I tried this :

```
Binding bind = new Binding();
bind.Source = this._vb;
this._container.SetBinding(Grid.DataContextProperty, bind);
```

But it did not work as expected so I tried this

```
Binding bindWidth = new Binding();
bindWidth.Source = this._vb.Width;
this._container.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, bindWidth);
Binding bindHeight = new Binding();
bindHeight.Source = this._vb.Height;
this._container.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, bindHeight);
```

I wanted to zoom the Viewbox to have its child zoomed as well and update the Grid parent of my Viewbox. I also tried to do the opposite way (zoom the grid binded to my viewbox but it did not work).

Does someone know why it happens ?

Comment: set Binding Mode bindWidth.Mode=BindingMode.TwoWay

Comment: It tells me I need Path or XPath to use a bidirectional Binding

Comment: Ah ok I tried with with the first solution I implemented. I thought it would be the same ><

Comment: It didnt change anything... I will try to find why. Thanks for your fast answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Width an Height properties to guide the calculation of Width and Height.  Try binding to ActualWidth/ActualHeight instead.

```
var binding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
binding.Source = this._vb;
this._container.SetBinding("Height", binding);
```

This will update the Height property on the _container to match the ActualHeight of the _vb object.

Comment: It works great. I just needed to specify a DependencyProperty into the SetBinding function. The "Height" didn't work and I just replaced it by Grid.HeightProperty. Just for information. Anyway thanks!